# How can I ensure network connectivity in an Ionic v3 app when the mobile phone has a connection

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

We’re developing an Ionic v3 application using Angular. 
Here we're facing the problem that we (sometimes) lose internet connection after entering or leaving our work wifi network and changing from/to cellular data. After that we’re unable to retrieve any data from our web api.
Eventhough the mobile device has network connection it is impossible to connect the internet from within our application.

The following code shows how we observe network changes:

```
import { Network } from '@ionic-native/network';

export enum ConnectionStatus {
    Online,
    Offline
}

@Injectable()
export class NetworkHelper {

    private status: BehaviorSubject<ConnectionStatus> = new BehaviorSubject(ConnectionStatus.Offline);

    constructor(private platform: Platform, public network: Network, public eventCtrl: Events) {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => { 
            this.initializeNetworkEvents();
        }
    }

    public initializeNetworkEvents() {
        this.network.onDisconnect().subscribe(() => {
            if (this.status.getValue() === ConnectionStatus.Online) {
                console.log('WE ARE OFFLINE');
                this.eventCtrl.publish('network:offline');
            }
        });

        this.network.onConnect().subscribe(() => {
            if (this.status.getValue() === ConnectionStatus.Offline) {
                console.log('WE ARE ONLINE');
                this.eventCtrl.publish('network:online');
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The only way so far to recover is to either turn on and off flight mode or restart the app manually. This of course is not acceptable for the user.

Did anybody face the same issue and knows how to solve it?

Thanks and best regards
Timon

Comment: how do you handle  'network:online' and 'network:offline' events ? .

Comment: initializeNetworkEvents method should be after device ready event.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari Thanks for your answer. I missed that part in the sample code. In fact we call initializeNetworkEvents after the platform ready event. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @FarabiAbdelwahed Thanks for your response. I'm not sure if I understand your question completely. We handle these events by subscribing to the this.network.onDisconnect() and this.network.onConnect() events...

Comment: @TimonFrei I am also using same to show user has internet or not but only different is i have added same code in app.ts file and it is working fine.

Comment: @KhurshidAnsari Ok, thx! I verified the network state in platform.resume (which I placed in app.component.ts -> platform.ready). Unfortunately network.type (from cordova-platform-network-information) is 'none' when the app resumes after leaving our wifi...